# Fourier transform of a Gaussian times a rational function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, fourier-transform

I am trying to compute the following Fourier transform

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\text{d}x\,e^{i k x}e^{-x^2/a^2}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$

where $\text{deg}P(x)+1\leq\text{deg}Q(x)$, and the roots of $Q(x)$ are all complex. I have tried doing integration by residues, but I have found that, when doing the natural extension $x\rightarrow z$ there is no way of defining a contour passing through infinity in which the integrand vanishes. I have also tried doing $x\rightarrow z,\,x^2\rightarrow |z|^2$, but then the integrand is not holomorphic.

Does anyone have any idea on a better extension to the complex plane or a better contour for doing the integration?

Comment: with the partial fraction decomposition, you can replace $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ by $\sum_n  \frac{c_n}{x-\rho_n}$ if all its roots are simple

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Nevertheless, this tip does not essentially simplify the problem, since we end up with the same type of integrals but with lower-degree polynomials. Am I right?

Comment: $G(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\omega(x-a)} e^{-x^2} \frac{dx}{x-a}$, $G'(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty i e^{i\omega(x-a)} e^{-x^2} dx= \ldots$

Comment: Very clever trick, thanks. However, when I later perform integrations on $\omega$ I get a to-be-fixed function of $a$ in the case in the problem, so the full expression is still unknown.

Comment: Plus, I have been trying what I believe you are trying to tell me (compute an integral which is in principle easy and then integrate in $\omega$, but checking numerically the results do not coincide. Still, thanks for your help

Comment: @Alex Did you find a solution to your problem? I have also stumbled on sth similar.

Comment: @tks unfortunately not, I am sorry.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. By the way, I think that what @reuns meant, was to find a differential equation that $G(\omega)$ satisfies and then solve the equation to find $G(\omega)$.

Comment: No, no worries, you don't need to apologize. I think I tried the differential equation method, but it didn't work for my case. Maybe for yours it does